# WebDriver - one instance of driver in many classes

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have 3 classes like below but when I try to run my test I get NullPointer (TestPage->input1). On debug I spotted that I have a second instantion of driver which is null. Can anyone help me what I did wrong and how to fix it? Shouldn't it work properly?

```
public class BaseScenario {

protected WebDriver driver;

 @BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Ed\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
}

@AfterMethod
public void TearDown() {
    driver.quit();
    }

}
```

'

```
public class TestsPage {

WebDriver driver;

public TestsPage(WebDriver driver)
{
this.driver=driver;
}

public void input1(){
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/form/fieldset/div[1]/input[1]")).sendKeys("Kuba");;

}

public WebElement input2(){
    WebElement input2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/form/fieldset/div[1]/input[2]"));
    return input2;
    }

}
```

'

```
public class Tests extends BaseScenario{

TestsPage pagee = new TestsPage(driver);

@Test
public void TC1() throws Exception {
    pagee.input1();
    pagee.input2().sendKeys("Chudy");
    }
}
```

Comment: You @BeforeMethod should be present in Testpage Class

Comment: How exactly? I don't get it ;(

Comment: Initialzed Driver value is not getting to the Condtructor of testpage

Comment: Move "pagee = new TestsPage(driver);" inside @Test method...

Comment: @Grasshopper You made my day :) Thank you, you helped me a lot :)